# Google GEO search tips

Tags: google-maps, search, google-maps-api-3

One question: How to implement GEO search tip as www.airbnb.com has?
When I start writing "Lond.." it auto-suggests "London" etc. The same with other points on map. Where to search information about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this blog post from Google](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/05/faster-address-entry-with-google-places.html) which describes how to use [Google Places Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete) to accomplish what you're asking about.

(Note: there's a good chance that airbnb.com uses something other than the Google Places API, probably an in-house service - actually I just viewed source and they are using Google Places API for something)

Comment: great, thanks! I found it a few seconds ago :) Now autocomplete works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

See [Demo](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)

The code that toes the work

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

   autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
```